# How to make a program run by BIOS?

Tags: c, boot, bios

I searched for info about this but didn't find anything.

The idea is:

If I code a program in C, or any other languages, what else do I need to do for it to get recognized in BIOS and started by it as a DOS program or just a prompt program?

I got this idea after I booted an flash drive with windows using the ISO and Rufus, which put some code in the flash drive for the BIOS to recognize it and run, so I would like to do the same with a program of mine, for example.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What you are asking is how to write your own OS, so start searching for info about that :)

Comment: Oh, i didnt realize that, haha. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An interesting, but rather challenging exercise!

The BIOS will fetch a specific zone from the boot device, called a master boot record. In a "normal" situation with an OS and one or more partitions, the MBR will need to figure out where to find the OS, load that into memory, and pass control to it. At that time the regular boot sequence starts and somewhat later the OS will be running and be able to interact with you. More detail on the initial activities can be found [here](http://www.dewassoc.com/kbase/hard_drives/master_boot_record.htm)

Now, for educational purposes, this is not strictly necessary. You could write an MBR that just reads in a fixed part of the disk (the BIOS has functions that will allow you to read raw sectors off a disk, a disk can be considered as just a bunch of sectors each containing 512 bytes of information) and starts that code. You can find an open source MBR [here](https://github.com/jhallen/bootext2/tree/master/mbr) and basically in any open source OS.

That was the "easy" part, because now you probably want to do something interesting. Unless you want to interact with each part of the hardware yourself, you will have to rely on the services provided by the BIOS to interact with keyboard, screen and disk. The traditionally best source about BIOS services is Ralf Brown's [interrupt list](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~ralf/files.html).

One specific consideration: your C compiler comes with a standard library, and that library will need a specific OS for many of its operations (eg, to perform output to the screen, it will ask the operating system to perform that output, and the OS will typically use the BIOS or some direct access to the hardware to perform that task). So, in going the route explained above, you will also need to figure out a way to replace these services by some that use the BIOS and nothing more - ie, more or less rewrite the standard library.

In short, to arrive at something usable, you will be writing the essential parts of an  operating system...

Answer (score 1):

Actually BIOS is going to be dead in the next two years (INTEL will not support any BIOSes after this date) so you may want to learn UEFI standard. UEFI from v2.4 allows to write and add custom UEFI applications. (BTW the "traditional" BIOS settings on the UEFI computers is often implemented as a custom UEFI App).

Comment: please post the authority to back your statements

Comment: @user3629249 `Forum earlier this month, Intel announced that by 2020 it was going to phase out the last remaining relics of the PC BIOS by 2020, marking the full transition to UEFI firmware.` - from the press release. Intel plans to cut 8086 real mode compatibility in the future processors. https://www.zdnet.com/article/intel-were-ending-all-legacy-bios-support-by-2020/